# Weird gradient when using CAGradientLayer with radial gradient.

Tags: ios, core-animation, cagradientlayer

Using code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let v = View()
        view.addSubview(v)
        v.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}

class View : UIView {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = .blue

        gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.type = .radial
        gradientLayer.colors = [
            UIColor.red.cgColor,
            UIColor.green.cgColor
        ]
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

expect(generated by Sketch): 
[image]

code result on a iOS 12 simulator:
[image]

code result on a real iOS device:
[image]

My Xcode version is 10.0 (10A255), I found the problem occurs only when
 `startPoint.x == endPoint.x || startPoint.y == endPoint.y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the y of startPoint and endPoint are equal, that means the height of the gradient ellipse will be 0.

In your code snippet, you can set entPoint's y to 1 to achieve the Sketch effect.

In the QuartzCore framework, there are the following comments:

> /* Radial gradient. The gradient is defined as an ellipse with its
>        * center at 'startPoint' and its width and height defined by
>        * '(endPoint.x - startPoint.x) * 2' and '(endPoint.y - startPoint.y) *
>        * 2' respectively. */
>
> @available(iOS 3.2, *)
>
> public static let radial: CAGradientLayerType

Comment: entPoint's y should be 1.5